# Is it possible to disable the "You've gone full screen" notification in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a HTML5 game but if I set the game into fullscreen if my cursor on the top it shows that notification?
I use this to set it into fullscreen:

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
      if (!document.fullscreenElement &&
          !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
          document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
          document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
          document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
      } else {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
          document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
          document.msExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
          document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
          document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the extent of my knowledge, **this is *not* possible in javascript**. The browser handles the showing of that notification to prevent websites from exploiting the user by going fullscreen without informing them, not showing them how to close it nor allowing them to.

Check out this answer for a bit more in-depth information:
https://superuser.com/questions/398945/disable-the-youve-gone-full-screen-notification-in-chrome

Also: https://groups.google.com/a/webmproject.org/forum/#!topic/webm-discuss/5vtRCwu50ZU

Answer (score 2):

I believe that, by design, it is not possible so that an application cannot takeover the screen for nefarious purposes.

Answer (score 1):

**No, you cant**..it's one of the default functionality of a browser. it's one of the security features implemented in browsers..

See more here https://groups.google.com/a/webmproject.org/forum/#!topic/webm-discuss/5vtRCwu50ZU